# using pandas to find number of duplicated sentences in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find out how much duplicated sentences does my dataframe has which is any exact match sentences repeated more than one, I'm using **Dataframe.Duplicated** but it ignore the first oucurency of the sentences and I want it instead of printing the duplicated sentences just print the duplicated sentences one and the number of its occurrence

the code I'm trying is

```
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)
data=wdata[wdata.duplicated()]
print(data)



#dataframe example
#hi how are you
#hello sam how are you doing
#hello sam how are you doing
#helll Alex how are you doing
#hello sam how are you doing
#let us go eat
#where is the dog
#let us go eat
```

I want my output to be something like

```
#hello sam how are you doing   3
#let us go eat                 2
```

with duplicated function I get this output

```
#hello sam how are you doing
#hello sam how are you doing
#let us go eat
```

this is the output I'm getting with second answer

```
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

data=wdata.groupby(['sentences']).size().reset_index(name='counts')


#                      sentences  counts
#0  hello Alex how are you doing       1
#1   hello sam how are you doing       3
#2                hi how are you       1
#3                 let us go eat       1
#4                let us go eat        1
#5              where is the dog       1
```

I want my output to be something like

```
#hello sam how are you doing   3
#let us go eat                 2
```

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: for my example its printing back even the sentences with occurrence one that is why I asked it seprateley

Comment: @jezrael I dont want it to return the sentences with 1 time occurrence any solution for that

Comment: Can you add your solution and explian, why not working? Not sure if understand

Comment: @jezrael I updated the question with output example

Comment: So you need `data=wdata.groupby(wdata['sentences'].str.strip()).size().reset_index(name='counts')
data = data[data['counts'].gt(1)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are whitespaces, solution is remove them by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
data=wdata.groupby(wdata['sentences'].str.strip()).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

And then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data = data[data['counts'].gt(1)]
```

Another idea is use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for Series, filtering and last convert to 2 columns DataFrame:

```
s = wdata['sentences'].str.strip().value_counts()
data = s[s.gt(1)].rename_axis('sentences').reset_index(name='counts')
```